# Analytic normals to a sphere displaced with Simplex Noise

Tags: opengl, glsl, normals, simplex-noise

I want to render a planet like sphere. The general idea is as follows:

- Generate a bunch of unit length vertices which make up a sphere.
- While rendering the sphere the shader evaluates the 3D simplex noise at the point on the unit sphere.
- The result is used as the "height" to displace the current vertex along its direction.

Up to here everything is working like it should.

Now I want to add lighting and therefore need normals to the surface.

While implementing the lighting related parts I quickly added a method to estimate the normals of the terrain using partial derivatives in the fragment shader like this:

```
vec3 X = dFdx(ins.position);
vec3 Y = dFdy(ins.position);
vec3 normal = normalize(cross(X,Y));
```

where `ins.position` is the interpolated world position.

While this works it does not look very good, because it essentially results in per-face normals.

[image: Bad normal approximation]

Now to the actual questions:

- Calculating per-vertex normals would result in smooth normals, unlike in the picture, correct?
- One of the advantages of Simplex Noise over Perlin Noise is that is has a "well-defined and continuous gradient everywhere that can be computed quite cheaply" (to cite the excellent [Simplex Noise demystified](http://www.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf)) and with the gradient one should be able to compute the normal, correct?

If the seconds question is a "yes" I have two problems:

- The simplex noise algorithm was taken from a [popular source](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise), which sadly does not include the gradient calculation. I will post my attempt of adding it below, but I have no idea if it is correct.
- Even if I had the gradient I am stuck on deriving the normal from there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My shot at the gradient implementation (replaced the last few lines of [snoise](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/blob/master/src/noise3D.glsl)):

```
float snoise(vec3 v, out vec3 grad)
{
    ......

    // Mix final noise value
    vec4 m = max(0.6 - vec4(dot(x0,x0), dot(x1,x1), dot(x2,x2), dot(x3,x3)), 0.0);
    vec4 m2 = m * m;
    vec4 m4 = m2 * m2;

    vec4 pdotx = vec4(dot(p0,x0), dot(p1,x1), dot(p2,x2), dot(p3,x3));

    vec4 temp = m2 * m * pdotx;
    grad = -8.0 * (temp.x * x0 + temp.y * x1 + temp.z * x2 + temp.w * x3);
    grad += m4.x * p0 + m4.y * p1 + m4.z * p2 + m4.w * p3;
    grad *= 42.0;

    return 42.0 * dot(m4, pdotx);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The part about calculating the surface normal from the gradient has been answered here:
[Surface normal to point on displaced sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071662/surface-normal-to-point-on-displaced-sphere).

The remaining question now is how to implement the gradient calculation into the GLSL version of the 3D Simplex Noise, because my implementation seems to have issues.

**UPDATE 2:**

The gradient calculation seems to be *almost* right, just the scaling seems to be off.
Instead of multiplying by 42, dividing by 5 gives pretty good results, but that was found out by trial and error. A proper scaling factor would be nice.

Comment: To answer your first question: yes and no. Per-vertex normals can be smooth if you have information about adjacent triangles, or they can be flat if you compute them using a single triangle. Using geometry shaders and a triangle strip with adjacency you can get up to 4 shared triangles per-vertex, which ***might*** (considering that is *not* actually the number of triangles that each vertex belongs to) be sufficient to compute an approximate smooth per-vertex normal. You will have to structure your input vertex indices in a very particular order to accomplish this and it requires GL 3.2+.

Comment: If I understood that correctly, the resulting normals will be smooth if the normal for a given vertex is the same, no matter what face is currently processed. Assuming the calculation works out the way I described that will be the case, because the normals will only depend on the information of the single vertex they belong to.

Comment: Well, the (smooth) per-vertex normal depends on the other 2 vertices in each triangle that shares that vertex. I look at your mesh and notice some vertices with as many as 10 triangles sharing the same vertex. If you wanted to smooth those per-vertex normals correctly, you would have to compute the face normal for all 10 of those triangles. That is why it does not seem practical.

Comment: You could avoid the issue by adjusting the spherical normal using GPU-calculated gradients in the fragment shader, via `dFdx` and `dYdx`.

Comment: @Justin you mean like the way I described in the question? ;)

Comment: You could calculate the normal in the vertex shader by evaluating the simplex noise at two more positions with small offsets from the vertex.

Comment: @GuyRT Yes I could, but evaluating the noise is expensive in comparison to the gradient and the latter would give perfect normals, not an approximation.

Comment: Inigo Quilez discusses getting the derivatives from perlin noise here: http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/morenoise/morenoise.htm - perhaps you could adapt his ideas

Comment: @Gigo whoops. I don't suppose you want to evaluate the noise function per-fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, turns out my problem was almost purely math related.

If anyone is interested:
The GLSL implementation of the gradient calculation posted in the question is totally correct.
Calculating the normals directly from the gradient is possible as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071662/surface-normal-to-point-on-displaced-sphere).

And the result looks exactly like I wanted it to be, I am happy ;)

[image: Smooth per-vertex normals]

Comment: Can you share some Code? i can't get this to work like you described.

Comment: I will try to dig up this project and put it on Github.

Comment: That would be nice :D